# Handling big images with VUEJS3.0

Tags: vue.js, memory

I want to use VueJs for displaying large format image display for the technical people in a specialised domain. They might  like to scroll, zoom, stack images and process the images with their front-end app.

Do you think VueJs 3.0 is ready for such an application? Is there any issue with the memory leaks in such an application with vueJS?

Regards

Prabhat

Comment: yes VueJS can, but as you asked that way I really like to see a sample or want to know how large it can be. put the maximum size please.

Comment: 15360 × 8640 to begin with

Comment: this wont make any issue unless your browser or pc makes

Comment: Great. I read somewhere there are chances of the memory leaks with VUE JS, That's why I was worried because the users would be frequent/severe with their operation with the images. They might even stack images for a purpose.